# PHP MySQL Treat GROUP_CONCAT results as separate items

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, group-concat

I am making a music classification database using PHP and MySQL.
I have three tables:

**Song:**

```
ID  | Title
------------------------
1   | Example Song
```

**Genre:**

```
ID  | Name
------------------------
1   | Classical
2   | Instrumental
```

**SongGenre**

```
SongID | GenreID
----------------
1      | 1
1      | 2
```

My Query is:

```
SELECT s.title, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT g.name SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM song s    
LEFT JOIN songgenre sg ON s.id=sg.s_id
LEFT JOIN genre g ON sg.genreid = g.id
```

I'm using GROUP_CONCAT to allow for multiple genres as shown:

> Title: "Example Song" Genres: Classical, Instrumental

I wish to generate a link in PHP for each genre, so that if the user clicks on "Classical" they are brought to more songs listed as Classical. The issue is, I am unsure how to give each genre its' own link. The issue with GROUP_CONCAT is that both genres are returned together in the same row, and I am unsure how to **split the row apart to add a link to each separate genre.**

Comment: the link would trigger a new query, which would select based on genre - well i think thats what you are asking

Comment: @Dagon I am aware how to actually create the query, my question is rather how to treat each genre as it's own link. I wish to have each genre as its' own separate link, which I am unaware how to do. I will update the question to make that more clear.

Comment: `<a href="search.php?genre=1">Classical</a>`

Comment: @Dagon  My issue is that MySQL returns "Classical, Instrumental" as one row, and I don't know how to actually split those apart to add the <a> attribute.

Comment: explode() on the comma, then loop

Comment: @Dagon This worked wonders. I would appreciate if you would put this as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: _“I am unsure how to split the row apart”_ – so you failed to perform even the most basic research such as googling [php split string at comma](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+split+string+at+comma) …?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a very basic example as requested by OP

```
$var="Classical, Instrumental";

$each=explode(', ',$var);

foreach($each as $v){
echo '<a href="search.php?genre='.$v.'">'.$v.'</a>';
}
```

Comment: I'll just state the obvious here and point out that this approach will fail if a genre name contains a comma.  Indeed, this approach is the third sign of "Pinball Programming" listed in the excellent article [Signs that you're a bad programmer](http://www.yacoset.com/Home/signs-that-you-re-a-bad-programmer).

Comment: I embrace my badness.

Answer (score 1):

Don't group within the database layer—return an ungrouped (*but sorted*) recordset to PHP and handle it from there:

```
$qry = $pdo->query('
  SELECT   sg.SongID, sg.GenreID, s.Title, g.Name
  FROM     song s
             LEFT JOIN songgenre sg ON s.ID = sg.SongID
             LEFT JOIN genre g ON sg.GenreID = g.ID
  ORDER BY sg.SongID, sg.GenreID
');

if ($qry) {
  echo '<ul class="songs">';

  $row = $qry->fetch();
  while ($row) {
    $current_song = $row['SongID'];

    echo '<li>'
       ,   '<span class="title">', htmlentities($row['Title']), '</span>'
       ,   '<ul class="genres">';
    do {
      echo   '<li>'
         ,     '<a href="genre.php?id=', intval($row['GenreID']), '">'
         ,       htmlentities($row['Name'])
         ,     '</a>'
         ,   '</li>';
    } while ($row = $qry->fetch() and $row['SongID'] == $current_song);

    echo   '</ul>'
       , '</li>';
  }

  echo '</ul>';
}
```